# If range has specific comment, show msg in another cell

Tags: vba, range, comments

I have this code in VBA and require it to show 'Final Bottling' in another sheet. Below is the code

```
Ip = input worksheet
op1 = Checks worksheet
i = 1
Cell = Ip.Cells(9, i + 2)
    If LCase(Left(Cell, 14)) = "final bottling" Then
                                                                                                '#Checks Final Bottling
            Op1.Cells(8, 5) = "Final Bottling Run, Please Consume materials. If unsure, check with materials planner!"
        
        Else
        
            Op1.Cells(8, 5) = ""

    End If 'Check
```

The message appears if all comments in the range C9:H9 have the comment 'Final bottling'. But if only one of the cells in that range has the comment it wont appear anymore.
Not sure what to do now, apologies if this sounds dumb and must be an easy fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will show the message if any of the cell in C9:H9 in Ip has "Final bottling"

```
Sub Test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim checkCell As Range
    
    Set checkCell = op1.Cells(8, 5)
    
    For i = 3 To 8
        Debug.Print LCase(Left$(Ip.Cells(9, i).Value, 14))
        If LCase(Left$(Ip.Cells(9, i).Value, 14)) = "final bottling" Then
            checkCell.Value = "Final Bottling Run, Please Consume materials. If unsure, check with materials planner!"
            Exit Sub 'Check is complete, exit sub from here
        End If
    Next i
    
    checkCell.Value = vbNullString 'code will only pass here if it fails all the check in the loop above.
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use Match function to check if the range contains the string and set message:

```
pos = 0
On Error Resume Next
pos = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("final bottling", Ip.Range("C9:H9"), 0)
' if not match (case insensitive), then error occurs and pos remains 0; if match was successful, pos = 1+
Op1.Cells(8, 5) = IIf(pos = 0, "", "Final Bottling Run, Please Consume materials. If unsure, check with materials planner!")
On Error GoTo 0
```

Another way is to use formula like this in cell Opt!E8:

> =IFERROR(IF(MATCH("final bottling",Ip!C9:H9,0)>0,"Final Bottling Run, Please Consume materials. If unsure, check with materials
> planner!",""),"")

Or use Ip.Range("C9:H9").Find() function